# How to force autofill on specific form?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofill

I am trying to implement autofill functionality in HTML5 form. But in Chrome it only autofills when it feels like it :( I have the autocomplete attribute like this:

```
<input autocomplete="name" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pnj9ogsL/1/

The first form does not work because it does not have "enough" autofill fields, I assume. Is there a way to force the browser to fill in the fields?

Comment: The only thing I have seen is <form autocomplete="on">